# Tkinter can't recognise file generated by matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

Hi I'm completely new to both of these libraries and to python in general. I'm trying to have a window pop up with a graph but it just returns the same error.

```
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


window = Tk()
window.title("Computer Science Glossary")
window.configure(background="black")

x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [3, 4, 8]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.title('Title')
plt.xlabel('xlabel')
plt.ylabel('ylabel')
plt.savefig('test.png')

photo1 = PhotoImage(file="test.png")
Label(window, image=photo1, bg="black").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

window.mainloop()
```

```
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "test.png"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Which version of Tkinter are you using?

Comment: It works fine with my `tk` version 8.6.12 (`print(window.call("info", "patchlevel"))`).

Comment: Keep in mind that the older versions of tkinter does not support PNG images directly and you may have to use `PIL`. Also worth noting that the file could be corrupted as well.

Comment: I'm using tkinter 8.5.9 and the files aren't corrupted

Comment: PNG is supported after tk 8.6.